# how can disable RecyclerView click listener but scroll working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have nested `RecyclerView` and disable click of my child `RecyclerView` with this way and use this class as my child `RecyclerView`.

```
public class MyDisabledRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    public MyDisabledRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyDisabledRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyDisabledRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }
```

My child `RecyclerView` inside another `RecyclerView` item and I want when click in child `RecyclerView`, go to parent `RecyclerView` item click, so I disable touch event of child `RecyclerView` but with this way child `RecyclerView` can not scroll any more, I try put child `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView` or `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` 
but still not working.

Comment: Are you facing problem with smooth scrolling of nested scrollview ?

Comment: @Karacken i try some ways like put recycler inside nested scrollview but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some research and thinking i do this : 
pass all i need in parent RecyclerView to child RecyclerView adapter constructor with position like below :

```
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ChatList_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.name.setText(chanelsList.get(i).getUser().getFirstname()+" "+chanelsList.get(i).getUser().getLastname());

        holder.city_recycler_hosts.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);
        holder.city_recycler_hosts.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        holder.city_recycler_hosts.addItemDecoration(new VerticalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(context).color(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.lightergray)).margin(0,20).
                build());

        CityHosts_Adapter adapter=new CityHosts_Adapter(chanelsList.get(i).getUser().getCities(),chanelsList,file,position,pusher
        ,auth,message_ist);
        holder.city_recycler_hosts.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

then in child RecyclerView do what we done in parent RecyclerView click , but we pass position of parent RecyclerView to constructor adapter of child RecyclerView so Instead use `getAdapterPosition` in child we use position that we got in constructor

Answer (score 2):

### To disable RecyclerView items click :

Add following view into your layout file for masking top of the view hierarchical.

```
 <View
     android:id="@+id/recyclerViewDisable"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/transparent"
     android:clickable="true"
     android:focusable="true"
     android:visibility="gone"/>
```

set this view visibilty `View.VISISBLE` when you want to disable recyclerview items click.If you want to enable items click then set visiblity `View.GONE`

### To scrollable when Recyclerview items click disable:

```
recyclerViewDisable.setOnTouchListener((view, motionEvent) -> {
            recyclerview.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            return true;
        });
```

Thats  works perfectly. If found workable then vote for correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: kind of little trick, but work perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
childRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap most parent `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView`.

```
<NestedScrollView
 ...>

   <RecyclerView
   .../>

</NestedScrollView>
```

and add `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);` on all `RecyclerView`.

By this you will not have conflicts in Scrolling in Child RecyclerView.

### Just a hack for your requirement

Wrap Child `RecyclerView` with another non clickable `View`. like

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="false"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**Note that.**

- Parent `FrameLayout` should be `wrap_content`.
- Child `RecyclerView` should be `wrap_content` with `nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`.
- Parent `RecyclerView` should be `nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`.
- Overlay `View` upon child `RecyclerView` should be `match_parent`.

**Understand** 
Here we set nestedScrolling false to child `RecyclerView`. So its scrolling will be disabled and it will take wrap_content height in parent `RecyclerView`. Now because we added a `View` upon it with non-clickable so child `RecyclerView` will not be touchable anymore.

Comment: i do but not scrolled !

Comment: i know your answer befor i aks my question , it scroll with normal recyclerview but not work with custom recycler view with disable click

Comment: You don't want Scrolling of RecyclerView by user?

Comment: Now i understand your problem, see answer.

Comment: still same problem ... nothing change . with normal recycler scroll wokr but click not work to going parent recyler item , and with custom disable touch click , click on it go to parent recycler but scroll not work

Comment: Where are you setting item click on parent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176215/discussion-between-erfan-and-khemraj).